# Monotonically increasing function

Tags: functions

i am trying to find an increasing function $\psi(\theta)$ such that $\psi(\theta) \in (-1, 0)$? I found $\psi(\theta) = \frac{1}{\theta}$ but it is going out of desired range.

Comment: oh sorry, i tried with $\psi(\theta) = - \frac{1}{\theta}$

Answer (score 1):

What about `y=x` defined within your range (you can use an indicator variable for your range)? It's definitely monotonically increasing.

Comment: Since domain is the positive real line, I was thinking it would be better to find a function $\psi(\theta)$ such that $0< \psi(\theta) +1< 1$. What can be the possible increasing function $\psi(\theta)$?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a monotonic function with domain in the whole real set and range in $(-1, 0)$, one obvious choice is the [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function):

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + \mathrm e^{-k(x-x_0)}}$$

Since the logistic function range is $(0,1)$, you should offset it by subtracting 1:

$$\psi(\theta) = \frac{1}{1 + \mathrm e^{-k(\theta-\theta_0)}}-1$$

Comment: I think logistic function is a good choice but here $\theta$ is defined on positive real line only.

Comment: @BAQA I'm not sure to understand you. If by "here" you mean in the logistic equation, it's support is the whole real line, including negative reals. If "here" means your problem, then you just need to restrict the function to positive reals.